# Reorder in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(Country = c("Indonesia","Indonesia","Brazil","Colombia","Mexico","Colombia","Costa Rica" ,"Mexico","Brazil","Costa Rica"),
            Subject = c("Boys", "Girls","Boys","Boys","Boys","Girls","Boys","Girls","Girls","Girls"),
            Value = c(358.000,383.000,400.000,407.000,415.000,417.000,419.000,426.000,426.000,434.000))
```

I'm trying to make a plot of Country vs Value, but ordering the points by the Value ascending for the Boys rows only. I know I can use something like:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Country, Value), Value)) +
  geom_point()
```

This does not take into account the Boys only rows in the subject column. How do I go about doing this?

Edit: The ordering can be done outside ggplot as:

```
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(Value, Subject)
```

However, I just cannot yet replicate it in the ggplot reorder. Included is an example of the data in question.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible so others can help. [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Thank you I will amend it to this standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arranging your data frame does not change the way the column `Country` will be ordered on the x axis.  The priority for the order on the axis for discrete variables is:

- If you supply a `reorder` or final specification in `aes()`, use that ordering
- If the column is a factor, use the order of the `levels` of that factor
- If the column is not a factor, order alphanumerically

As far as I know, you can only specify one column to use in `reorder()`, so the next step is to convert to a factor and specify the `levels`.  The way the items appear in the ordering of the data frame does not matter, since the columns are treated completely separate from the order in which they appear in the data frame.  In fact, this is kind of the whole idea behind mapping.

Therefore, if you want this particular order, you'll have to convert the `Country` column into a factor and specify `levels`.  You can do that separately, or pipe it all together using `mutate()`.  Just note that we have to specify to use `unique()` values of the `Country` column to ensure we only provide each level one time in the order in which they appear in the sorted data frame.

```
# color and size added for clarity on the sorting
df %>%
  arrange(Subject, Value) %>%
  mutate(Country=factor(Country, levels=unique(Country))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Country, Value, color=Subject)) + geom_point(size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great thank you I never though of using levels in this case I was so fixated on value.

Comment: It's natural to think that the order of your data = the order of the plot, but that's basically the idea behind mapping.  Each column is taken independently and mixed together based on what is linked in your dataset.  It's almost best to picture `ggplot` taking apart your data frame by column, then only maintaining that value X in each column is linked by observation.  The order only signifies how it's linked, but not actually how it's ordered.